# Write query result from twitter4j into csv using opencsv

Tags: java, twitter4j, opencsv

I'm using twitter4j to extract tweets from twitter. After i use this line i get a json result:

```
QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
```

I want to know how to use opencsv to write this into csv. writeAll() is only for List or result set, I want to know what i can do with my query result. 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use `writeAll()` directly, as you'll need to build a `List<String[]>` beforehand.

Alternatively you could use [`CSVWriter#writeNext(String[])`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html#writeNext%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) to write individual Tweets whilst iterating through [`QueryResult#getTweets()`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/QueryResult.html#getTweets%28%29), for example:

```
for (final Status status : result.getTweets())
{
    final String[] line = new String[] { Long.toString(status.getId()), status.getText(), ... };
    writer.writeLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but status.getId() is Long, how can I change to String?

Comment: Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type long

Comment: @user2481451 Sorry thought you said `Long` and not `long`, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create a `List<String>` from the tweets and then only you can write it using `CSVWriter`:

```
List<String[]> lines = new ArrayList<>(result.getTweets().size());
for(Status status : result.getTweets()) {
    lines.add(new String[] { status.getText() });
}
// write the lines using CSVWriter
```